# python session requests image download - forbidden access 403

Tags: python, image, python-requests, session-cookies, urllib

I am trying to download an image from an url, with python requests.session also adding user-agent, still facing 403 forbidden error, please help.

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
s = requests.session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}



#logged in! cookies saved for future requests.
r=s.get("https://example.com/homepage",headers=headers)
#cookies sent automatically!

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
te=s.get("https://www.example.com/"+soup.find(class_='yes').find('a').get('href'),headers=headers).text

s.get('https://img.example.com/exampleimgcode.jpg', stream = True,headers=headers}))

out[]: <Response [403]>
```

Comment: What server side logic is required to authenticate?  If you don't know, then it sounds like everything is working correctly.

Comment: I dont know the server side logic. All I see is the homepage startswith `www.example.com` and image page is like `img.example.com`